# Is there a way to delete inbox notices, not just mark them as read?

Tags: support, global-inbox

Stack Overflow [recently released new inbox enhancements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live).  When I go into the "full inbox", it shows that I have **1836 *pages*** of notices, going back 12 years.  I don't need all of those messages, is there any way to actually delete them, not just mark them as read?

Comment: Nope, deleting isn't supported

Comment: Even if you could delete them, we'd just hide them rather than removing them from the database, so... yeah. :) We're the ultimate hoarders... we never delete anything.

Comment: [We need a mechanism for 'purging' seen inbox messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371414/348196)

Comment: @Catija I never understood why the system works that way. I can understand if something gets deleted and needs to be undeleted in a short amount of time. But after awhile, it should just be allowed to expire and disappear completely. No need to keep hanging around.

Comment: Is there harm in them hanging around *forever*?

Comment: @KevinB Other than just wasting resources on the server?

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is not our concern so will never be a valid argument for a meta post.